# R for loop help to trim based on condition

Tags: r, for-loop, trim

I am new to R and struggling with for loop:
I want to split some strings in a df based on condition
my df:
[image: MyDF]

I want to split where begins with "X"
to identify I am using - `grepl("X.",df1[,1])`
to split - `str_split_fixed(df1[,1],"X",2)[,2]`
and not sure how to incorporate that in the loop...

```
for (i in df1[,1]){
  # if (begins with X) then split
}
```

so the goal here is to strip "X" from df rows (11 & 12)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Perhaps there are many other alternatives, but I am specifically interested to use for loop option. Thanks!

Comment: (1) Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly. (2) What is your expected output?

Comment: my expected output is to strip "X" from rows 11 and 12 by using for loop option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R is a vectorized language, so you can just substitute the leading `"X"` with `""` in one line.

```
df1[,1] <- sub("^X", "", df1[,1])
```

Using for loop would be very inefficient in this case, but if you insist on that, then

```
for (i in seq_along(df1[,1])) {
  if (substr(df1[i,1],1,1) == "X")
    df1[i,1] <- substring(df1[i,1],2)
}
```

Data

```
df1 <- structure(list(header1 = c("PLAYERID", "YEARID", "STINT", "TEAMID", 
"LGID", "G", "G_BATTING", "AB", "R", "H", "X2B", "X3B", "HR", 
"RBI", "SB", "CS", "BB", "SO", "IBB", "HBP", "SH", "SF", "GIDP", 
"G_OLD")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

Comment: Thank you all for your solutions and advice.

Comment: Also, would be very grateful if someone could share any good articles or videos about the loops how and what's happening behind the scenes.  Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

for loop

```
for(i in seq_along(df$header1)){ df$header1[i] <- sub("^X","",df$header1[i]) }
df
      header1
1    DGIGACAE
2  DFGGFAEHBD
3        BIBH
4          EB
5      DHBDFC
6         2BD
7        3GDE
8     DEAEFGE
9           I
10    FFBGDBD
```

Better vectorized

```
df$header1 <- sub("^X","",df$header1)
df
      header1
1    DGIGACAE
2  DFGGFAEHBD
3        BIBH
4          EB
5      DHBDFC
6         2BD
7        3GDE
8     DEAEFGE
9           I
10    FFBGDBD
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(header1 = c("DGIGACAE", "DFGGFAEHBD", "BIBH", 
"EB", "DHBDFC", "X2BD", "X3GDE", "DEAEFGE", "I", "FFBGDBD")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

## `stringr` solution

I realize you wanted to use the loop, and the other 2 solutions gave you that, plus a vectorized solution.  If you're working with the `tidyverse`, you can use `str_replace` to do this as well:

```
df1 <- structure(list(header1 = c("PLAYERID", "YEARID", "STINT", "TEAMID", 
                                  "LGID", "G", "G_BATTING", "AB", "R", "H", "X2B", "X3B", "HR", 
                                  "RBI", "SB", "CS", "BB", "SO", "IBB", "HBP", "SH", "SF", "GIDP", 
                                  "G_OLD")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))

df1

library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% mutate(header1 = str_replace(header1, "^X", ""))
```

### Output:

```
     header1
1   PLAYERID
2     YEARID
3      STINT
4     TEAMID
5       LGID
6          G
7  G_BATTING
8         AB
9          R
10         H
11        2B
12        3B
13        HR
14       RBI
15        SB
16        CS
17        BB
18        SO
19       IBB
20       HBP
21        SH
22        SF
23      GIDP
24     G_OLD
```

So... you have lots of options.  I think the other answers better your direct question, though.